# Fetch all records from #tbl1 which are not in #tbl2 without use of 'NOT' keyword

Tags: sql

- Here we have two tables (#tbl1 and #tbl2)

## tbl1 Record

```
Id  Name
---------
1  Durgesh
2  Ashish
3  Ramesh
4  Steve
5  Pradeep
```

## tbl2 Record

```
Id  Name
---------
2  Ashish
5  Pradeep
```

Result Should be given below without using 'NOT' Keyword

```
Id  Name
---------
1  Durgesh
3  Ramesh
4  Steve
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below Code :

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM #tbl1 
EXCEPT
SELECT Id,Name FROM #tbl2
```

The above code uses EXCEPT keyword to find the result. This query is Tested in SQL Server.

Comment: Welcome! You can use joins as well for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.id,A.name
from #tbl1 A
left outer join #tbl2 B on A.id = B.id
where B.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM #tbl1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tbl2 t2 WHERE t2.id <> t1.id);
```

Some DBMS supports lateral JOIN :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM #tbl1 t1 OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT T2.*
       FROM #tbl2 t2
       WHERE t2.id = t.id
     ) t2
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```